# iOS Message Extension with CocoaPods: Invalid Bundle

Tags: swift, xcode10

I have a standalone iMessage Extension with Cocoapods.

Xcode: 10.1
Min SDK Target: 11.0
CocoaPod Version: 1.5.3

My CocoaPods File:
     platform :ios, '11.0'

```
 target 'App' do
   use_frameworks!
 end

 target 'App MessagesExtension' do
   use_frameworks!
   pod 'Alamofire'
   pod 'Firebase/Core'
 end
```

I can run my Extension in Simulator. After uploading App (App Extension) I get:

```
 Invalid Bundle - Ensure that app executables and bundled frameworks use consistent architectures
```

What I figure out is that "Container" App contains "Architectures: armv7, armv7s, and arm64" but my Extension and all Frameworks only "arm64".

```
 "Build Active Architecture Only" is set to "NO"
```

Someone use CocoaPods in successfully in their App Extension App?

I appreciate any kind of hints or links!

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: Did anyone solve this ?